# PHP type error on creating admin menu item

Tags: administrator, menu-item

When I try to create an admin menu item in Joomla 5 (I imagine the same will apply to Joomla 4), I get this error:

```
An error has occurred.
0 strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
```

I see this issue has been reported [here](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=995445) and [here](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/39758). In those cases the error was coming from the OSMap extension. I don't have that extension installed, but I am still getting the error.

I am using Joomla 5.0.0 with PHP 8.1.24.

I would be grateful for guidance on how to solve the problem.

Thank you!

Update:
Here is the debugging information:

```
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/Model/MenutypesModel.php:414
2   strlen()     
3   array_filter()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/Model/MenutypesModel.php:414
4   Joomla\Component\Menus\Administrator\Model\MenutypesModel->getTypeOptionsFromManifest()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/Model/MenutypesModel.php:175
5   Joomla\Component\Menus\Administrator\Model\MenutypesModel->getTypeOptionsByComponent()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/Model/MenutypesModel.php:109
6   Joomla\Component\Menus\Administrator\Model\MenutypesModel->getTypeOptions()     JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/AbstractView.php:159
7   Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\AbstractView->get()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/View/Menutypes/HtmlView.php:62
8   Joomla\Component\Menus\Administrator\View\Menutypes\HtmlView->display()     JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:697
9   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/src/Controller/DisplayController.php:74
10  Joomla\Component\Menus\Administrator\Controller\DisplayController->display()    JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:730
11  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute()     JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:143
12  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
13  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:150
14  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:195
15  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:306
16  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:58
17  require_once()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:32
```

Comment: hi bruce please enable debug and post here the additional information so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you,  Marco, I have edited the post and added the debugging info.

Comment: Is the Joomla 5 instance a new fresh installation or have you upgraded from a Joomla 4 instance? The text in the two items you have linked too suggest that an existing com_something has used a now invalid string the creation of its menu item(s). If it is a new installation of Joomla 5 then you would have seen at the extension was installed but with an upgrade of Joomla 4 the menu structure isn't recreated until you try to create a new item. I would suggest looking through the 3rd party component manifest files for not normal looking entries between the <menu> elements, particularly [ or ] .

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, Irata. This is an upgrade from Joomla 4 — and, in fact, from Joomla 3 before that — so there could well be a component that is not using the right format for its menu items. I will try your suggestion.